# Wrong order on rows and function not running on AJAX async false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm running a function that moves table rows from one table to the other and stores it to the database. I was running this async but ended up with rows stored in the wrong order. Basically it is so fast so even if jQuery each is looping through in the right order the result comes out in whatever order finishes first, on microsecond level. I bet there are neater solutions, but setting async to false solved it. I know people are not recommending doing it that way though so how can I otherwise make sure that my rows are stored and presented in the right order?

I'm also wondering why my showLoader() and removeLoader() functions are not running when I set async to false?

```
$('#move-rows-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(document).showLoader();
    $(this).closest('.project').find('.sub-table tbody tr').each(function() {
        var row = $(this);
        var id = row.data('id');
        var response;
        $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
             url: "?ajax=move_row&id="+id,   
             async: false
        }).done(function(response) {
            if( response != 0 )
            {
                row.detach().appendTo('#main-table tbody').attr('id', 'rowid-'+response);
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).removeLoader();
});
```

Comment: Never use `async: false`. All it does is create another problem. Also looping through all the rows in your table and sending an AJAX request for each is a bad idea for multiple reasons - not least because you're flooding your server with requests. Instead, put the data from all `tr` elements in the table in a single request - and in the right order - then deal with them in one go on the server. This will avoid both bottlenecking and concurrency issues

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sounds logical. Thanks. What's the best way to get all the rows into an array that can be sent with ajax? Still jquery each or is there a smarter way?

Comment: You can use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to build an array of objects from a set of elements. If you get stuck, I'd suggest starting a new question that includes the HTML of your table

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Brilliant. If you don't mind, I still wonder why showLoader(); and removeLoader(); stopped working when switching async to false? This is showLoader() `$('<div class="loader-img"></div>').appendTo('body');` and removeLoader(); `$('.loader-img').remove();`

Comment: That's a side effect of `async: false`, and part of the reason you should never use it. In simple terms it blocks the UI thread of the browser from updating while the AJAX request is in progress. This means that although you appended an element, it will not be displayed as the browser did not have time to show it, and cannot do anything while it waits for the AJAX response. Then when the request completes, the element is immediately removed, so it's probably shown for a few milliseconds (at most), which isn't enough for a human to notice.

Comment: In addition, you'll get console warnings telling you not to use synchronous XHR, and also if the request goes on too long, some OS will warn the user that the browser is no longer responding and ask if they want to force close it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Aha, I get it. I've never used map() before. That will come in handy! Last thing. I found a way to use map() to get my row id's (ints) into a comma separated string that I can send. Then on the server side I'll create an array and loop through it. Good or should I try to create the array already on the client side?

Comment: Either is absolutely fine, so long as it meets your needs. Personally I'd use an array and let jQuery encode it :)